# How to compute the propinquity of a graph in R?

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I would like to test if the geographical location of my vertices (ie I have a matrix giving the distance between each pair of actors of my network) has an influence on the presence/absence of edges. If I have correctly understood, this feature is called propinquity....

In other words, I would like to know if two vertices are more likely (or less likely) to be connected if their distance is small.

Do you have any idea of how to do that in R? I usually use igraph but if another library does that I will use it of course :-).

Comment: Is there an "official" definition of propinquity that you want to use?

Comment: Not really, I just want to test this connection likeliness. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Okay, then how about this: create two vectors, one holding the distances for connected actors and one holding the distances for pairs of actors that are not connected, then run a [Mann-Whitney U test](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) on them. You can use the `wilcox.test` function for this.

Comment: Wow, that's a really good idea. Simple and straight to the point. I'm a bit jalous I didn't tought about it by myself. Thank you ! Il will try that and hope it gets results.